# use pymongo as class to query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I wrote class that suppose to connect mongoDB as database

```
class DB:
   def __init__(self,hostName ,port):
      self._conn = myDB.Connection(hostName, port)
      self.mydb = _conn['mydb']
      self.mycollection = mydb["recipe"]

   def find_name(self, name :str):
      return self.mycollection.find({"name": name})
```

now I want to query from this database

so I ran

```
dd = mydb("localhost", 27017)
```

and I want to use  the `find_name(name)` function.
Buy I got

> dd = mydb("localhost", 27017)
>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

the question is how to make a DB class and use it for query from other `.py` file.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably named your pymongo file as `mydb.py` & you're probably importing your PyMongo module like so:

```
import mydb
```

And then calling it like so:

```
dd = mydb('localhost', 27017)
```

The issue is, that `mydb` is a module. That's not the same thing as the class `DB` that you have defined *inside* `mydb`. You need to create an object of `DB`. You can do that by:

```
dd = mydb.DB('localhost', 27017)
```

Or, by like this:

```
from mydb import DB
...
dd = DB('localhost', 27017)
```